# How do I store TableRowSorter SortKeys for future use?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablerowsorter

I am trying to store a the `SortKey`s of a `TableRowSorter` for a `JTable` so that I can recall them next time the screen loads and apply them.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
static void saveSortKeys(String name, JTable table) {
    List<? extends SortKey> sortKeys = table.getRowSorter().getSortKeys();
    if(sortKeys.size() > 0) {
        Preferences prefs = ...;
        prefs.putInt("sortOrder_count", sortKeys.size());
        int i = 0;
        for(SortKey sortKey : sortKeys) {
            prefs.put("sortOrder_name_" + i, sortKey.getSortOrder().toString());
            prefs.putInt("sort_column_" + i, sortKey.getColumn());
            i++;
        }
    }
}

static List<SortKey> getSortKeys(String name) {
    Preferences prefs = ...;
    int count = prefs.getInt("sortOrder_count", 0);
    List<SortKey> keys = new LinkedList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int column = prefs.getInt("sort_column_" + i, -1);
        SortOrder so = SortOrder.valueOf(prefs.get("sortOrder_name_" + i, ""));
        SortKey key = new SortKey(column, so);
        keys.add(key);
    }
    return keys;
}
```

I thought it'd be best to use the `Preferences` api, so I wrote some methods to do this. However, I'm concerned because it relies on the enum `SortOrder::toString()` method to store and `SortOrder.valueOf` method retrieve the enum, which just seems like a bad idea to me. Also, you have to manually store the size of (and iterate through) the `SortKey` list.

Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: Maybe [JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/)

Comment: Actually, your approach seems like an ideal way to do it.  Table sort order is one of those things that probably belongs in Preferences, since it's a non-critical user setting.  I don't see anything wrong with using the toString and valueOf methods of SortOrder, since they're guaranteed to behave symmetrically.

Comment: I forgot another concern: this (paired with a RowSorterListener) means that the SortKeys list will constantly get larger and larger as time goes on. I wonder if I should just store the very last sort key (`sortKeys.get(sortKeys.size() - 1)`) instead of all of them...

Answer (score 0):

You should encapsulate the behavior of both `Preferences` and `List<Sortkey>` in your own custom object. By using a [Decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), you can easily control how this functionality works. First, use a very basic implementation that only supports runtime storing of the `SortKey`s.

```
interface SortKeyManager {
  void saveSortKeys(String name, List<SortKey> sortKeys);
  List<SortKey> getSortKeys();
}

public class SimpleSortKeyManager implements SortKeyManager {
  private List<SortKey> sortKeys;

  void saveSortKeys(String name, List<SortKey> sortkeys) {
    this.sortKeys = sortKeys;
  }

  public List<SortKey> getSortKeys() {
    return sortKeys;
  }
}
```

Then, add a decorator that supports saving and loading to the Preferences.

```
public class PreferencesSortKeyDecorator implements SortKeyManager {
  private final SortKeyManager manager;
  private final Preferences preferences;

   public PreferencesSortKeyDecorator(SortKeyManager manager, Preferences preferences) {
     this.manager = manager;
   }

   public void saveSortKeys(String name, List<SortKey> sortKeys) {
     manager.saveSortKeys(name, sortKeys);
     saveToPreferences(name, sortKeys);
   }

   private void saveToPreferences(String name, List<SortKey> sortKeys) {
     // your code
   }

   public List<SortKey> getSortKeys() {
     List<SortKey> keys = manager.getSortKeys();
     if(keys == null) {
       // Your code to load from Preferences
     }
   }
 }
```

Finally, inject the SortKeyManager into your JTable's constructor:

```
public class YourTable extends JTable {
  private final SortKeyManager manager;

  public YourTable(SortKeyManager) {
    this.manager = manager;
  }
}
```

This configuration will give you complete control over the way everything works and obeys the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and the [Open Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle). It also no longer binds your implementation to the way Preferences works, as it's an add-on effect to using the decorator version.